# How to write the equations with conditions in two lines?

Tags: equations

I want to write the boundary condition in the following form. Need your help to write the below equations in two lines

[image]

Comment: Micky, it would be really cool if you could improve your questions by at least typing in the equations as code and don't leave all that to the answerers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really want to use `alignat` or `alignedat` (the difference being that the former types two equations, the latter one equation on two lines)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat}{8}
    \nu &= V_w &&= cz/l, & \qquad u&= U_0, &\qquad \text{at\quad} r &=R, \\
    \nu &\rightarrow V_e &&= az/l, &\qquad T &\rightarrow T_{\infty},&\qquad \text{as\quad} r &\rightarrow \infty,
  \end{alignat}

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{8}
      \nu &= V_w &&= cz/l, & \qquad u&= U_0, &\qquad \text{at\quad} r &=R, \\
      \nu &\rightarrow V_e &&= az/l, &\qquad T &\rightarrow T_{\infty},&\qquad \text{as\quad} r &\rightarrow \infty,
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{alignedat}{8}
      \nu &= V_w &&= cz/l, & \qquad u&= U_0, &\qquad \text{at\quad} r &=R, \\
      \nu &\rightarrow V_e &&= az/l, &\qquad T &\rightarrow T_{\infty},&\qquad \text{as\quad} r &\rightarrow \infty,
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

both environments are found in `amsmath` , which is loaded by `amsart` in my mwe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `amsmath` package by using `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble of your document and try this,

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \nu = V_w = cz/l,    &&        u= U_0,           & \text{at} && r &=R, \\
& \nu \to V_e = az/l,  && T \rightarrow T_{\infty}, & \text{as} && r &\to \infty,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

With this code you will get the single equation no. The output is here,

[image]

Try to avoid the following code with `tabular` environment. See the comments of @Johannes_B.

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
$\nu = V_w = cz/l,$ &  $u= U_0,$ & at $r =R,$ \\
$\nu \rightarrow V_e = az/l,$ & $T \rightarrow T_{\infty}$& as $r \rightarrow \infty, $
\end{tabular}
```

Here is my output,

[image]

Comment: Are you really suggesting to use `eqnarray`? What about `align`?

Comment: Tabular or eqnarray? There are many better solutions. And spacing of the type `\hspace{4.2mm}` should be avoided.

Comment: @Johannes_B and @Kola, I agree that using `\hspace` is not a good thing, so I edited the answer. But I don't know why it is bad to use `tabular` environment. Could you please tell me.

Comment: This is obviously a `display`ed equatin, but you are in text mode within the tabular. This is more obvious when introucing integrals or sums.

Comment: @ddas I need the two equations with the single equation number

Comment: MickyK see the comments above and check the answer. Hope this will help. Thanks to @Johannes_B.